# Building precompile mock results in error[E0277]: the trait bound `currencies::MultiCurrencyPrecompile<TestRuntime>: Precompile` is not satisfied

Tags: frontier, evm, testing, mock

I am currently implementing a mock for our EVM precompiles but ran into the following error when building the tests

```
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `currencies::MultiCurrencyPrecompile<TestRuntime>: Precompile` is not satisfied
   --> runtime/common/src/mock.rs:205:25
    |
205 |     type PrecompilesType = Precompiles;
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Precompile` is not implemented for `currencies::MultiCurrencyPrecompile<TestRuntime>`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <currencies::MultiCurrencyPrecompile<Runtime> as Precompile>
```

However, the precompile trait is already implemented for `MultiCurrencyPrecompile`.
Here is the implementation:

```
pub struct MultiCurrencyPrecompile<Runtime>(PhantomData<Runtime>);

impl<Runtime> Precompile for MultiCurrencyPrecompile<Runtime>
where
    Runtime: currencies::Config + pallet_evm::Config + frame_system::Config,
    Runtime: Erc20Mapping,
    currencies::Pallet<Runtime>:
        MultiCurrencyTrait<Runtime::AccountId, CurrencyId = FungibleTokenId, Balance = Balance>,
    U256: From<
        <<Runtime as currencies::Config>::MultiSocialCurrency as MultiCurrencyTrait<
            <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        >>::Balance,
    >,
    BalanceOf<Runtime>: TryFrom<U256> + Into<U256> + EvmData,
    <<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::Call as Dispatchable>::Origin: OriginTrait,
{
    fn execute(handle: &mut impl PrecompileHandle) -> PrecompileResult {
        let address = handle.code_address();

        if let Some(currency_id) = Runtime::decode_evm_address(address) {
            log::debug!(target: "evm", "multicurrency: currency id: {:?}", currency_id);

            let result = {
                let selector = match handle.read_selector() {
                    Ok(selector) => selector,
                    Err(e) => return Err(e),
                };

                if let Err(err) = handle.check_function_modifier(match selector {
                    Action::Approve | Action::Transfer | Action::TransferFrom => FunctionModifier::NonPayable,
                    _ => FunctionModifier::View,
                }) {
                    return Err(err);
                }

                match selector {
                    // Local and Foreign common
                    Action::TotalSupply => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::BalanceOf => Self::balance_of(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::Allowance => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::Transfer => Self::transfer(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::Approve => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::TransferFrom => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::Name => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::Symbol => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                    Action::Decimals => Self::total_supply(currency_id, handle),
                }
            };
        }
        Err(PrecompileFailure::Revert {
            exit_status: ExitRevert::Reverted,
            output: "invalid currency id".into(),
        })
    }
}
```

Also here is the implementation of the `MetaverseNetworkPrecompiles` used as `Precompiles` value:

```
impl<R> PrecompileSet for MetaverseNetworkPrecompiles<R>
where
    R: pallet_evm::Config + currencies::Config,
    MultiCurrencyPrecompile<R>: Precompile,
    Dispatch<R>: Precompile,
{
    fn execute(&self, handle: &mut impl PrecompileHandle) -> Option<PrecompileResult> {
        let address = handle.code_address();

        //      if self.is_precompile(address) && address > hash(9) && handle.context().address != address {
        //          return Some(Err(PrecompileFailure::Revert {
        //              exit_status: ExitRevert::Reverted,
        //              output: b"cannot be called with DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE".to_vec(),
        //          }));
        //      }

        match address {
            // Ethereum precompiles :
            a if a == hash(1) => Some(ECRecover::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(2) => Some(Sha256::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(3) => Some(Ripemd160::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(4) => Some(Identity::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(5) => Some(Modexp::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(6) => Some(Bn128Add::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(7) => Some(Bn128Mul::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(8) => Some(Bn128Pairing::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(9) => Some(Blake2F::execute(handle)),
            // nor Ethereum precompiles :
            a if a == hash(1024) => Some(Sha3FIPS256::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(1025) => Some(Dispatch::<R>::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(1026) => Some(ECRecoverPublicKey::execute(handle)),
            a if a == hash(1027) => Some(Ed25519Verify::execute(handle)),
            // Metaverse Network precompiles
            // If the address matches asset prefix, the we route through the asset precompile set
            a if &a.to_fixed_bytes()[0..9] == ASSET_PRECOMPILE_ADDRESS_PREFIX => {
                Some(MultiCurrencyPrecompile::<R>::execute(handle))
            }
            // Default
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn is_precompile(&self, address: H160) -> bool {
        //      sp_std::vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 400]
        //          .into_iter()
        //          .map(hash)
        //          .any(|x| x == address)
        true
    }
}
```

Here is also the  part of the mock file which gives the build error

```
pub type Precompiles = MetaverseNetworkPrecompiles<TestRuntime>;

parameter_types! {
    pub NetworkContractSource: H160 = H160::from_low_u64_be(1);
    pub const ChainId: u64 = 2042;
    pub BlockGasLimit: U256 = U256::from(u32::max_value());
    pub PrecompilesValue: Precompiles = MetaverseNetworkPrecompiles::<_>::new();

}

impl pallet_evm::Config for TestRuntime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Currency = Balances;

    type BlockGasLimit = BlockGasLimit;
    type ChainId = ChainId;
    type BlockHashMapping = EthereumBlockHashMapping<Self>;
    type Runner = pallet_evm::runner::stack::Runner<Self>;

    type CallOrigin = EnsureAddressRoot<AccountId>;
    type WithdrawOrigin = EnsureAddressNever<AccountId>;
    type AddressMapping = HashedAddressMapping<BlakeTwo256>;

    type FeeCalculator = ();
    type GasWeightMapping = ();
    type OnChargeTransaction = ();
    type FindAuthor = ();
    type PrecompilesType = Precompiles;
    type PrecompilesValue = PrecompilesValue;
    //type WeightInfo = pallet_evm::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
}
```

Full implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/feature/precompile-mock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by implementing Erc20Mapping mock implementation together with implementing both Precompile and PrecompileSet for the precompile + setting a mock PrecompileSet implementation.